# Pandas - Column sorting changes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, columnsorting

I am trying to merge set of csv files into one Dataframe. In the process I create a new column called **Time_Created** which I am trying to have as the first column of the Dataframe.

```
df_v1 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in updatedfiles_1], sort=True)
cols = df_v1.columns.tolist()
print(cols) 
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('Time_Created')))
print(cols) <-- This shows the columns as expected
df_v1.to_csv('file.csv')
```

I see when printing the columns before saving to csv the columns are modified as required but when I open the saved csv the column sorting changes.

Given below is the sequence of columns in the source:

```
Name,Price,Quanity,Time_Created
```

Sequence that I am trying to sort into:

```
Time_Created,Name,Price,Quanity
```

Could anyone guide me why is the output file changes the column sorting. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `df_v1.columns = cols` after you modify `cols`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are close.  You never actually set the columns of the dataframe to your modified order.  You can do something like this and it should work.

```
df_v1 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in updatedfiles_1], 
                  sort=True)
cols = df_v1.columns.tolist()
print(cols) 
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('Time_Created')))
print(cols) <-- This shows the columns as expected
df_v1[cols].to_csv('file.csv')  <-Here you tell it to send df_v1 in [cols] order
```

If the last `print(cols)` is the order you want then you can just use it when sending the `df_v1` to_csv.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df_v1[['Time_Created', 'Name', 'Price', 'Quanity']].to_csv(...)`

Comment: i have a problem and that is the columns are not fixed. Each time the set of the columns in the Dataframe would vary but only the column "Time_Created" will be constant and hence trying this approach..